# How to convert .P12 to .Pem certificate using asp.net/C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, private, amazon-sns

I need to extract Certificate and Private Key, RSA Private Key encoded base64 content between tags below from .p12 file using c#.

```
--BEGIN CERTIFICATE----
   content
---END CERTIFICATE----

---BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----
--END PRIVATE KEY--

----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY---
----END RSA PRIVATE KEY---
```

I can able to extract Rawdata property from `X509Certificate2` object. But not able to extract Private Key.

```
 byte[] appleCert = null;
 appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath, "P12\\" + p12File));
 string certData = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" + Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.RawData) + "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
```

Please help me how to extract private key from X509Certificate2 object.